# Reinstall OS on a dual-boot system?

Tags: 12.04, mac, powerpc

I have an old (2005) iMac G5 with a PowerPC processor. It currently runs MacOSX and Ubuntu 12.04. I believe that the bootloader I use is yaboot.
Anyway, Ubuntu 12.04 runs really sluggish so I installed the LXDE desktop. I really like it, and would like to completely wipe my Ubuntu partition and replace it with Lubuntu, without affecting my MacOSX partition. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. In LDXE, use Synaptic and ensure that `lubuntu-desktop` is installed fully. Then, uninstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-netbook`. You now have(effectively) a Lubuntu system.

Edit: I saw your comment, and I need to see that you need to remove `gnome` and all of its dependencies(Automatically done when you remove the package)

Edit 3 due to Elijah Kagan's comment:

You may want to run :

```
sudo apt-get remove acpi-support acpid activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center adium-theme-ubuntu aisleriot apg app-install-data-partner appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt apt-xapian-index apturl apturl-common at-spi2-core avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon bamfdaemon baobab binutils bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty checkbox checkbox-qt cmap-adobe-japan2 colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf cups-bsd dc deja-dup doc-base duplicity dvd+rw-tools empathy empathy-common eog espeak espeak-data evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common example-content firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support folks-common fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-opensymbol fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree foomatic-db-engine gcalctool gcc gcc-4.6 gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine growisofs gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x guile-1.8-libs gvfs-bin gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hplip hplip-data hwdata ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase ibus-table indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-status-provider-mc5 intel-gpu-tools kerneloops-daemon landscape-client-ui-install laptop-detect launchpad-integration libart-2.0-2 libasound2-plugins libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor-schemas libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-core7 libavahi-gobject0 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libbrlapi0.5 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcairo-perl libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse libcmis-0.2-0 libcolord1 libcompizconfig0 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcupsdriver1 libcurl3 libcurl3-nss libdaemon0 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-4 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook-1.2-12 libecal-1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver-1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libespeak1 libexempi3 libexiv2-11 libexttextcat-data libexttextcat0 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libgail-common libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgexiv2-1 libglew1.6 libglewmx1.6 libglib-perl libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1 libgtk2-perl libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell-3-0 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libhpmud0 libhyphen0 libidl-common libidl0 libido3-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-0 liblcms1 liblouis-data liblouis2 liblua5.1-0 libmetacity-private0 libmission-control-plugins0 libmng1 libmysqlclient18 libmythes-1.2-0 libnotify-bin libnss-mdns libnux-2.0-0 libnux-2.0-common liboauth0 libopencc1 liborbit2 liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-perl libpangomm-1.4-1 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpulsedsp libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtbamf1 libqtcore4 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libqtgui4 libquadmath0 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libraw5 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core5 librsync1 libsane-hpaio libsensors4 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libsonic0 libspeechd2 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstlport4.6ldbl libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtelepathy-farstream2 libtelepathy-logger2 libtimezonemap1 libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-5.0-5 libunity-misc4 libunity9 libutempter0 libuuid-perl libvncserver0 libwacom-common libwacom2 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 light-themes linux-headers-3.2.0-24 linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-libc-dev mahjongg make manpages-dev media-player-info metacity metacity-common mousetweaks mscompress mtools mysql-common nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd notify-osd-icons nux-tools obexd-client onboard oneconf overlay-scrollbar pcmciautils pinyin-database pkg-config plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-desktop-privileges pptp-linux printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix protobuf-compiler pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-brlapi python-configglue python-dateutil python-debtagshw python-dirspec python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-gconf python-gi-cairo python-gst0.10 python-imaging python-libproxy python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-openssl python-packagekit python-pam python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pyinotify python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-serial python-speechd python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-virtkey python-xapian python-zeitgeist qdbus qt-at-spi radeontool remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone rtkit samba-common samba-common-bin sane-utils seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell sni-qt software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins speech-dispatcher ssh-askpass-gnome syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support toshset totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-punjabi-fonts ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-precise ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer unity unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote unity-services uno-libs3 update-inetd ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino whois whoopsie wodim xbitmaps xcursor-themes xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xfonts-mathml xterm xul-ext-ubufox yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal && sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

to remove Ubuntu, but be sure to have LDXE installed by then...

Comment: Thank you!I also installed the Gnome shell, and I've tried a LOT of things to get rid of it. How can I remove that?

Comment: Just make sure you don't accidentally remove `ldxe` or `lightdm`

Comment: You rock! But, I un-installed "The GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components", but it still shows up in the shell selector?

Comment: I'll take a look and add a new question

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/4645/how-do-you-add-a-new-window-manager-to-the-gdm-menu and delete the correct .desktop file from the folder(You'll see which you need to delete). Also, if you screw up, it's possible to fix this with the virtual terminals. If you need to, I'll tell you how. Also, be sure to accept this answer if it helps so other users know this solves your problem. :-)