# installed i3, but no WindowManager choice present on login (Gdm / Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome, 18.04, window-manager, gdm, i3-wm

I have a default install of 18.04 desktop.  I've installed `i3`, which succeeded, including creating `/usr/share/xsessions/i3.desktop` as in [How do you add a new window manager to the gdm menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4645/how-do-you-add-a-new-window-manager-to-the-gdm-menu)

On the gdm login screen, there is no gear or similar to change window managers.

Help! thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to perform a full reboot, or at least restart gdm, to update the list of sessions, and thus also see your new i3 session. In GDM, the cog icon to select your session is available after having selected your name.

Comment: Even after following this, I can't see i3 in the list. It seems installing i3 did not put anything under /usr/share/xsessions

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Had the same issue when installing i3-gaps. Installing `i3-gaps-session` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl restart gdm` might get it running again